# ConfigureProperty<MsmqTransport> in NServiceBus 3.0

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I'm upgrading a project from NServiceBus 2.6 to 3.0.

We have code similar to the example posted at http://docs.particular.net/samples/hosting/nservicebus-host/#nservicebus-host-v3_x

```
NServiceBus.Configure.With()
  .Log4Net()
  .DefaultBuilder()
  .XmlSerializer()
  .MsmqTransport()
     .IsTransactional(false)
     .PurgeOnStartup(false)
  .UnicastBus()
     .ImpersonateSender(false)
  .RunCustomAction(() => 
     Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureProperty<MsmqTransport>(mt => mt.Address, "someQueue")
   )
  .CreateBus()
  .Start();
```

When I try to compile code similar to this with 3.0, it complains that MsmqTransport can't be found. Is there a new way to achieve the same result in 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yup you now need to tell it you want to create queues on start if they arent there, take a look here [Not creating queues automatically in NServiceBus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105098/not-creating-queues-automatically-in-nservicebus)

or basically use

```
.Start(() =>Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install());
```

Comment: Ok.. so where do I set the address (or other properties) using that way?